# How can I make this RequireJS client-side app render faster?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, single-page-application

I've created project comparing time to render of a server-side vs. a client-side app here: http://performance-test.chadjohnson.io/. The source is here: https://github.com/chaddjohnson/performance_test.

The app uses Rails 4. The **server-side test** simply renders a view via ERB (it also loads a RequireJS module, but that's irrelevant to time to render for this test). The **client-side test** loads and uses Backbone, Marionette, jQuery, and Underscore to render a view.

The client test takes two times as long for me (~1000ms) as the server test (~500ms) to render. *I'd like to reduce the render time for the client test.*

As you can see here, I've implemented build layering: 1) require.js; 2) common.js, which contains core libraries (Backbone, Marionette, jQuery, and Underscore), and 3) main.js, which contains just the application stuff. I'm using requirejs-rails, so you can see the build config at config/requirejs.yml.

[image: Build layering]

**Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to decrease *render* time for the client?** Some constraints are that I need to use Backbone, Marionette, and RequireJS.

Comment: You can refine, **loading** time or **rendering** time? It's not the same...

Comment: I updated the post, changing "load time" to "render time."

Comment: bundling your scripts together should knock ~ half a second off if your image is correct.

Comment: I assume you mean combine main.js and common.js into one. True. Unfortunately I can't do that because my actual application uses this build layering, and this POC needs to do the same :(

Comment: i think - there's nothing to do. ceteris paribus browser faster compared with any library...